# assign students to group based on scores and campus - ASP.NET, VB and SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a table full of student details that contain columns "campus" and "gpa"
There are 2 types of groups, A and B.

Group A is for complex projects, and Group B is for non-complex projects.
These projects are specified in a table called "projectdetails".

I need to sort the students by campus, and then assign them to groups (A or B) based on their GPA.
There can be a max of 5 students per group.

The amount of group A groups is based on the number of complex projects. So, I need to select the top x (x= n of complex projects * 5 students) students to be in A class groups, and then randomly assign them to a group.
The remaining students will be assigned to a random B group.

I am having a bit of trouble figuring out how to implement the logic behind the function to assign students to groups. Would anyone out there be able to give me a hand?

This is how I envision it should work - but I am open to suggestions...

```
Sort by campus
Sort by gpa

Put each campus in separate array

for each campus {

Get the number of complex projects

x = complex projects * 5
select top x students {
            they are type a
            randomly assign to group (Max number of groups = number of  complex projects)
        }

select students that aren't type a {
            they are type b
            randomly assign to group (Max number of groups = number of  type b students / 5)
        }
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would remove some of the tags if you want to get an answer. Your question is only related to mysql, it has nothing to do with VB/C#/ASP. Only if you want your answer using PURE sql (not db vendor specific), should you tag it "sql". Just FYI

Comment: i don't mind what language I do it in, as long as it is using ASP.NET - as long as I can get the logic behind it right.

Answer (score 0):

I work in .NET (vb.net) and I'd setup your database using EntityFramework so that you can have objects (tables) of Campus, Student and Student Group.

```
Public Class assignStudents

Public Sub assignStudentsToGroups()
          Dim campList As New List(Of String)() From {"camp1", "camp2", "camp3"}
    Dim stuList As New List(Of stu)
    '  stuList  = select * stu's from database order by highest gpa first. pass in campusID
    Dim qtyComplex As Integer = 10
    Dim grpList As New List(Of grp)
    '  grpList = select * groups from db & qty of users in each grp.
    Dim qtyStudentsComplexGroup As Integer = qtyComplex * 5
    Dim count As Integer = 0

    '   for each campus
    For Each c As String In campList

        '   For each student in this campus
        For Each s As stu In stuList

            '   only loop round number of stu's that you want.
            '   i.e. the amount of complex projects * 5
            If count < qtyStudentsComplexGroup Then

                '   These are clever kids, need to go in Type A. 
                '   Loop through the list of all available groups

                For Each g As grp In grpList

                    '   Check to see if that group is full (student count = 5)
                    If g.qty = 5 Then
                        '   it's full. Don't add them to this.
                    Else
                        '   it's not full, add student to this group.
                        '   add sql insert statement.
                        '   pass in student ID, grpID. GrpType A
                    End If
                Next
            Else
                For Each g As grp In grpList

                    '   Check to see if that group is full (student count = 5)
                    If g.qty = 5 Then
                        '   it's full. Don't add them to this.
                    Else
                        '   it's not full, add student to this group.
                        '   add sql insert statement.
                        '   pass in student ID, grpID. GrpType B
                    End If
                Next
            End If

            '   increment the loop
            count += 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
End Class
Public Class stu
Private _name As String = ""
Public Property name() As String
    Get
        Return _name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        _name = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private _gpa As String = ""
Public Property gpa() As Integer
    Get
        Return _gpa
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
        _gpa = Value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
Public Class grp
Private _name As String = ""
Public Property name() As String
    Get
        Return _name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        _name = Value
    End Set
End Property
Private _qty As Integer
Public Property qty() As Integer
    Get
        Return _qty
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
        _qty = Value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```